Google Chat: Unable to mention users added to a group via Subteam (Group)
When adding multiple users simultaneously to a space in Google Chat via subteam(Group), I am unable to mention these users within the subteam using the syntax <users/person_id>. This prevents my chat bot from functioning correctly with those users (in chat, only the text <users/> is displayed instead of mentioning).
Is there any way to mention users belonging to a subteam via the API using either person_id or email?
I have referred to the documentation pages at:
https://developers.google.com/workspace/chat/identify-reference-users
https://developers.google.com/workspace/chat/format-messages
https://support.google.com/chat/answer/13535086?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop

I'm facing same issue. I believe that this is a bug on a google side. I create a ticket https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/335695512
